# Reputation league is stuck at Sept 15th

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation-leagues

As titled. The reputation leagues of all sites and all time intervals have not been updated since September 15th.

Comment: +1 - I noticed this myself earlier today, although hadn't pinned down the exact date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the report.  This should be fixed now.